# What's the parameters on Arduino callbacks?

Tags: arduino

I'm reading a code that uses Arduino as a webclient and when he tries to catch the info from the site, he uses a callback with the following parameters:

```
static void response_callback (byte status, word off, word len)
```

Can anyone explain me how does each one of this parameters work exactly?

Comment: You're probably better served here: http://arduino.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

This question is already solved at the arduino stackexchange. Look here for the answer:
https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/22417/can-someone-explain-me-the-parameters-on-arduino-callbacks